# how to rollback the transaction of a stored Procedure calling in another procedure in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, db2

I am calling a stored procedure into another stroed proceudre, now if first stored procedure gives any error then i want to rollback the transation of that stored procedure, as DB2 commit the transaction of Stored Procedure after the call completed.

So how to do that?

Comment: Could you provide details on the flow? The regular behavior is that the changes of the inner stored procedure would be rolled back, too. DB2 also has so called "autonomous transactions", but you would need to explicitly make the called procedure use that.

Comment: Suppose I am calling a Procedure A into another which has name B, so if now if there is any error occurs in the procedure A then it will not be rolled back because i am calling it in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds like your application executes `CALL B()`.  And the stored procedure `B` executes the `CALL A()` statement.

Unless either of the stored procedures include a `COMMIT` statement (which goes against best practices), then it is up to the calling application to determine if the `CALL B()` statement was successful or not, and decide whether to issue the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statement.  Executing `ROLLBACK` should roll back any/all changes made by `B` and `A`.

Comment: actually i am calling a Procedure into another Procedure, when my parent procedure gives any error then it can not be rolledback the transaction committed by child procedure, which i am calling in that
so do u know that how to rollback the trasaction ?

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates what is going on.

Comment: I resolve it own my own using the atomic in db2.
Thanks